# Karaoke as a place

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Karaoke is a form of entertainment, not a place, as far as I understand. The place where people can sing karaoke would be a karaoke venue, e.g. a karaoke bar.

So, I got confused when I saw the phrase "go to karaoke" in a Japanese textbook (it was used in my task written in English; by the way in Japanese "karaoke ni iku", which literally means "go to karaoke" is OK). The article "[5 Tips for Not Sucking at Karaoke](https://www.gq.com/story/5-tips-for-not-sucking-at-karaoke)" added to my confusions because "karaoke" means a place in the context.

How correct is it to say "go to karaoke" and "sing at karaoke"? How would you invite someone to go to a karaoke place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not particularly natural phrases, though I don't think anyone would misunderstand or think twice about it if they heard you say that.  Karaoke is not a place (unless there is a particular bar with this name).  You also would not use "at" with something that is not a place, such as karaoke.

Normally speaking, in English, you would specify *where* you are going in this case

> Let's go to a karaoke bar.

That's pretty much what anyone would say.

Alternatively, you could specify the activity with a verb

> Let's go do some karaoke.
>
> Let's go sing some karaoke.

The addition of "some" here is something of a colloquialism that makes it a little more playful. To me it seems right because karaoke doesn't exactly seem like a suggestion for a formal situation. You could remove it to be, I guess, a little more proper.

> Let's go sing karaoke.

The article you reference uses "karaoke" in a way I haven't heard, but I don't exactly hang around people who do karaoke much. Possibly people who do it a lot use the Japanese phrasing in a way that is not common among the rest of us?